# substring from string display error message

Tags: c#

I am trying to get youtube video id using this code, but it display this error message

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
> Parameter
>   name: length

the code:

```
string lnk = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BYphSyf0qY";
int endpoint = (lnk.IndexOf('&') > 0) ? lnk.IndexOf('&') : (lnk.Length - 1);
int startpoint = lnk.IndexOf("v=");
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This answer does not treating the question, but a cleaner alternative to get you want).*

You can use [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Need reference `System.Web`):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BYphSyf0qY");
System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("v");
```

Answer (score 0):

SubString has a start point and a length instead of a endpoint:

```
string lnk = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BYphSyf0qY";
int endpoint = (lnk.IndexOf('&') > 0) ? lnk.IndexOf('&') : (lnk.Length - 1);
int startpoint = lnk.IndexOf("v=");
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint-startpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are giving total length of the string/url as second argument.

**Solution :** `Substring()` takes second argument as length/number of characters tobe extracted.

So second argument should be the remaining length of the string from the startpoint.

**Try This :** if you want to get ID as -> `v=9BYphSyf0qY`

```
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint - startpoint);
```

**Try This :** if you want to get only ID part without `v=`  -> `9BYphSyf0qY`

```
startpoint += 2;
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint - startpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an index (a position within the string), as well as your code for the second case, when `IndexOf` returns `-1` (`lnk.Length - 1`), and you need to provide length of a sub-string as a second parameter for the [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call, like this:

```
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint - startpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int endpoint = (lnk.IndexOf('&') > 0) ? lnk.IndexOf('&') : (lnk.Length);
int startpoint = lnk.IndexOf("v=")+2;
lnk = lnk.Substring(startpoint, endpoint-startpoint);
```

No need to take one from length, but remember to add 2 to startpoint.  Finally length of substring should be endpoint-startpoint.

**results:**

```
Startpoint = 31 
Endpoint = 42 
ID = 9BYphSyf0qY
```